# How to change method signature with custom annotation

Tags: java, annotations, aop, method-signature

So long story short I want

```
@Version(1)
public Boolean isAlive() {
    return true;
}

@Version(2)
public Boolean isAlive() {
    return false;
}
```

To Compile. Then use AOP to map the flow to the correct method based on a global constant. Is that possible using Java 8?

I am aware there are other design patterns that won't run into this issue but I came across this question and wondered if anyone would know the answer.

Comment: Are these methods in the same class?

Comment: "*Is that possible using Java 8?*" - Not without further black magic. Annotations are only additional information for either documentation or runtime information. The code you provided is syntactically incorrect (you have a name clash). You would have to adjust the compiler for this to compile.

Answer (score 0):

> So long story short I want

... to find a contrived solution to fix your broken code which is invalid Java. This is not what AOP is meant to be used for. Your design is just broken. BTW, your subject

> **How to change method signature with custom annotation**

is also wrong because you do not want to change the method signature at all. Instead, you want the impossible: to make the compiler accept two methods with identical signature (only different annotations).

Long story short also from me: What you want neither makes sense nor is it possible. Sorry.